# Initialize the first index of a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I am converting something I wrote in C++ to Python. Here is a snippet of what I am trying to rewrite in python:

```
std::vector<int> dates(numberOfPayments.size(), 0);
dates[0] = NDD[0] - '0';
for (int i = 1; i < dates.size(); ++i)
{
    dates[i] = (dates[i - 1] + 12 - numberOfPayments[i - 1]) % 12;
}
```

The problem I am having is that I cannot set the first index of my list in python to something. I try this:

```
dates = []
dates[0] = NDD_month[0]
for i in range(len(first_payments)):
    dates[i] = (dates[i-1] + 12 - first_payments[i-1]) % 12
print(dates)
```

But I get this error:

```
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: List that you initialized is empty. Try dates.append(). Also in the next line you would probably like to loop from 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having this problem because you're trying to access a index that was not allocated yet.

To append things to a list you should use `append` (**edited to fix loop**):

```
dates = []
dates.append(NDD_month[0])
for i in range(1, len(first_payments)):
    dates.append((dates[i-1] + 12 - first_payments[i-1]) % 12)
print(dates)
```

Comment: I want to highlight the fact that I only fixed the `append` part. Your loop is starting in 0 and your logic will access a index `-1`. It will not break an error because Python allow access to negative indexes (it accesses your list backwards), but I don't think this is what you intended to do, is it?

Comment: Please see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53384396/matrix-vector-operations-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Since you initialized `date` with `[]`, it is empty with a size of 0. You will need to use `append()` to add elements to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your `dates` like that:

```
dates = [NDD_month[0]]

for i in range(len(first_payments)):
    dates[i] = (dates[i-1] + 12 - first_payments[i-1]) % 12
print(dates)
```