# Matrix vector operations in Python

Tags: python, list, matrix

I made a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53384285/initialize-the-first-index-of-a-list-in-python). Now I am trying to generalize what was done there for an entire matrix of numbers.

Specifically I want to do this:

```
dates = []
dates.append(NDD_month[0])
for i in range(1,len(cpi)):
    dates.append((dates[i-1] + 12 - number_of_payments[:i]) % 12)
print(dates)
```

where the `number_of_payments` is a matrix of type `<class 'list'>`.

Here is an example:

```
print(number_of_payments[:1])
```

is

```
[array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 5, 1, 0, 2, 1]])]
```

After performing what I want then

```
print(dates[:1])
```

Should be

```
[array([[8, 8, 7, 7, 6, 5, 4, 4, 11, 10, 10, 8]])]
```

or something like that.

**EDIT:**

Here is an example of what my data looks like:

```
print(number_of_payments[:3])
```

This gives me this:

```
[
    array(
    [
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 5, 1, 0, 2, 1]
    ]),
    array(
    [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
    ]),
    array(
    [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0]
    ])
]

print(NDD_month[:3])
```

Gives me

```
[8, 7, 11]
```

Now for the answer I want I want to do something like this that I did in my earlier post where I had

```
dates = []
dates.append(NDD_month[0])
for i in range(1, len(first_payments)):
    dates.append((dates[i-1] + 12 - first_payments[i-1]) % 12)
print(dates)
```

This gave me the correct output of

```
[8 8 7 7 6 5 4 4 11 10 10 8]
```

But now since I have the `number_of_payments` being a matrix I need to apply the same logic to this larger data structure. Let me know if that is clear.
**Edit 2:**

Okay this is hard to explain so I am going to go step by step example, I have this data or matrix (number_of_payments) whatever it is in python:

```
    [[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 5, 1, 0, 2, 1],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0],
     [1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]]
```

I have another list or vector called NDD_month, the first three elements are

```
[8, 7, 11]
```

Now for sake of simplicity lets say I  just have the first row of number_of_payments i.e.

```
[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 5, 1, 0, 2, 1]
```

Further for simplicity lets say I have just the first element of NDD_month so

```
8
```

Then to get the answer I seek I would do this that Aurora Wang provided a nice answer too which was this

```
first_payments = number_of_payments[:1]
first_payments = first_payments[0][0]
dates = []
dates.append(NDD_month[0])
for i in range(1, len(first_payments)):
    dates.append((dates[i-1] + 12 - first_payments[i-1]) % 12)
print(dates)
```

This gives me `[8, 8, 7, 7, 6, 5, 4, 4, 11, 10, 10, 8]`.

Now I need to do the same thing but for each row in the matrix and each element in the NDD_month vector. I hope that makes it much more clear.

I was thinking this may work but again I am new to python and this does not work:

```
dates = []
for i in range(1,len(NDD_month)):
    dates.append(NDD_month[i-1])
    for j in range(1, len(NDD_month)):
        dates.append((dates[j-1] + 12 - number_of_payments[i-1][j-1]) % 12)
print(dates)
```

Comment: You create a list just by doing `[]`..  Where is `cpi` defined?

Comment: cpi is just a list with a certain length that I know is doing to be the same

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 If my question does not make sense please clarify I will provide an example

Comment: Could you please edit your question to make it more clear? Can you also provide the full content of `number_of_payments`?

Comment: Also, from your previous post I don't think you're accessing your list the way you intend to. When you do `number_of_payments[:i]` you'll get a subset of your list that goes from index `0` to index `i` (what is not what your C++ code was doing).

Comment: @AuroraWang I made an edit let me know if that is clear

Comment: why don't you do something like `for array in number_of_payments:`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I am super new to python so I am not sure how to do that

Comment: I'm not very sure what you're trying to accomplish in either set of code, but you can loop over each array in the matrix using the loop construct I posted in my previous comment.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 So you did not understand my edit? I can provide more context if that would help?

Comment: I don't get what are you trying to do, what does your `number_of_payments` represents? Was it suppose to be a multi-dimensional matrix?

Comment: @AuroraWang yes here let me do another edit.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what NDD is.

Comment: I guess NDD could contain the start values for whatever calculation is going on, but I don't know how would this works as it seems to be a list but the matrix is suppose to have multiple dimensions.

Comment: @AuroraWang I made a new step by step example, please let me know if that is more clear...

Comment: @AuroraWang I may need to make the matrix into an actual matrix because when I print(number_of_payments[0][0]) I get [0 1 0 1 1 1 0 5 1 0 2 1] so I have no idea how to access each element :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you right, you want to do something like this:

```
number_of_payments = [
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 5, 1, 0, 2, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
]
NDD_month = [8, 7, 11]
dates = []
for i in range(len(number_of_payments)):
    dates.append([NDD_month[i]])
    for j in range(1, len(number_of_payments[i])):
        dates[i].append((dates[i][j-1] + 12 - number_of_payments[i][j-1]) % 12)
print(dates)
```

Comment: Yes that seems right but do you know how to convert the number_of_payments to be like that from how it is currently which is [array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 5, 1, 0, 2, 1]]), array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]]),

Comment: Do you want to flatten your arrays into a list of lists?

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx Are you using an external library?  `array()` is not built-in

Comment: Actually I think your code works fine its just taking awhile to run since the len(number_of_payments) is 1346

Comment: I got this: IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.

Comment: Guessing its just too much memory any idea how to make this work?

Comment: Actually should be fine, do you know how I print the first row of dates?

Comment: `print(dates[0])`?

Comment: I just get [8] when it should be [8, 8, 7, 7, 6, 5, 4, 4, 11, 10, 10, 8] for the first row

Comment: Maybe be flattening my arrays to a list of list will do it, do you know how to do that?

Comment: Although I didn't did the most pythonic solution ever, I did a simple one that I thought it would be easier for you to understand (given that you don't know Python very well). But I didn't know that you were dealing with large amounts of data and although you really tried to explain, it was sort of confusing. I have to go now, but I recommend you review SO's [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and I wish you good luck.

Comment: PS: I think you should try to isolate what you're trying to do in small problems. It's much easier to find/get answers to small problems. Like the flattering arrays one, someone probably already answered it in Stack Overflow. And even if there is no such question, I'm sure if you ask following the guidelines you have an answer soon. Try not to accumulate question above question in the same post, you can have your post flagged or people won't be able to help you properly.

Comment: I tried to do the exact same thing that you did but with my larger list of lists and I get a weird result...

Comment: I made a new post here since you cannot continue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53384990/strange-output-error-following-example-of-matirx-vector-operation-in-python