# Flatten arrays into a list of lists

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have this data structure:

```
[array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 5, 1, 0, 2, 1]]), array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]]), array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], etc....
```

I want to flatten this into a list of lists something like:

```
[[0 1 0 1 1 1 0 5 1 0 2 1]
 [1 6 1 0 0 1 1 1 2 0 2 0]
 [2 0 5 0 5 2 2 0 6 3 2 2]
 [1 0 1 1 1 1 0 2 0 0 0 1]]
```

How do we do this in python?

Comment: Why would you need to do this? And what have you tried? This is pretty basic...

Comment: @Julien Can you provide an answer since it is very simple

Comment: can you please provide a real example of input ... it is hard to tell with the input provided

Comment: look into np.hstack vstack etc and reshape...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `vstack`:

```
>>> np.vstack(l)
array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 5, 1, 0, 2, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Note that this is equivalent to:

```
>>> np.concatenate(x, axis=0)
array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 5, 1, 0, 2, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

To convert to list, use `tolist`:

```
>>> np.vstack(l).tolist()
[[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 5, 1, 0, 2, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

# or

>>> np.concatenate(x, axis=0).tolist()
[[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 5, 1, 0, 2, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: I get the same type of output though

Comment: this does not work for his input ... see my start of a repl https://repl.it/@JoranBeasley/LimegreenSecondaryRuntimes

Comment: @JoranBeasley, works for me, adding `print(numpy.vstack(a))` returns the stacked array

Comment: I stand corrected ... I thought this suffered from the same issue as the flatten solution

Comment: [array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 5, 1, 0, 2, 1]]), array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]]), array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0]]), array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 5, 1, 0, 2, 1],
       [1, 6, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0],
       [2, 0, 5, 0, 5, 2, 2, 0, 6, 3, 2, 2],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1]]), array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 5, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0],

Comment: Still get that output

Comment: Perhaps see this post which is why I made this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53384396/matrix-vector-operations-in-python

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx, I'm not sure why, I don't get that output. There might be something weird going on later in the array.

Comment: This computer is having issues that was not suppose to be poosted to your answer

Comment: Please post your suggested edit to your question, rather than to my answer :)

Comment: Please see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53384990/strange-output-error-following-example-of-matirx-vector-operation-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Use `flatten`:

```
print([i.flatten() for i in l])
```

Or:

```
print(list(map(lambda x: x.flatten(),l)))
```

Both output:

```
[array([0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 5, 1, 0, 2, 1]), array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,
   0]), array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0])]
```

Comment: im not sure this will work its weird arbitrary number of lists in each array

Comment: that does not match his input ... try https://repl.it/@JoranBeasley/LimegreenSecondaryRuntimes