# Strange output error following example of matirx vector operation in python

Tags: python, list, numpy, matrix

I want to do this in python, here is a small example:

```
number_of_payments = [
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 5, 1, 0, 2, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
]
NDD_month = [8, 7, 11]
dates = []
for i in range(len(number_of_payments)):
    dates.append([NDD_month[i]])
    for j in range(1, len(number_of_payments[i])):
        dates[i].append((dates[i][j-1] + 12 - number_of_payments[i][j-1]) % 12)
print(dates)
```

This gives me

`[[8, 8, 7, 7, 6, 5, 4, 4, 11, 10, 10, 8], [7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 5, 5, 5, 4], [11, 10, 7, 6, 6, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1]]`

Now I try to do the same thing but with the entire set of data but this is what I get (I will paste my whole code below):

```
# Import modules
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# Import data file
df = pd.read_csv("Paystring Data.csv")
df.head()

# Get column data into a list
x = list(df)

# Append column data into cpi, NDD, and as of dates
NDD = df['NDD 8/31']
cpi = df['Contractual PI']
as_of_date = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(df.columns.str[:8], errors='coerce'))
as_of_date = as_of_date[1:13]
NDD_month = pd.to_datetime(NDD, errors = 'coerce').dt.month.tolist()
# print(as_of_date.dt.month)

# Get cash flows
cf = df.iloc[:,1:13].replace('[^0-9.]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
cf = cf.values

# Calculate number of payments
number_of_payments = []
for i in range(len(cpi)):
    number_of_payments.append((cf[:i + 1] / cpi[i]).astype(int))
np.vstack(number_of_payments).tolist()

# Calculate the new NDD dates
dates = []
for i in range(len(number_of_payments)):
    dates.append([NDD_month[i]])
    for j in range(1, len(number_of_payments[i])):
        dates[i].append((dates[i][j-1] + 12 - number_of_payments[i][j-1]) % 12)
print(dates[0])
```

This just gives me `[8]`

When it should be `[8, 8, 7, 7, 6, 5, 4, 4, 11, 10, 10, 8]`.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I suggest you step through a debugger. Your precondition is that your `number_of_payments` is a list of lists; does that precondition hold in your real code?

Comment: @erip No idea how to do that in jupyer notebook nor with python I am a c++ programmer

Comment: A jupyter notebook is basically an interactive debugger.

Comment: @erip Do you have any idea what could be causing these issues?

Comment: If I had to guess, your data is malformed. You might want to step through a debugger, though.

Comment: @erip Which data? the number_of_payments data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your "small example", `number_of_payments` is a `list` of `list` of `int`s:

```
number_of_payments = [
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 5, 1, 0, 2, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
]
```

In your real code, `number_of_payments` is a `list` of `int`s:

```
number_of_payments = []
for i in range(len(cpi)):
    number_of_payments.append((cf[:i + 1] / cpi[i]).astype(int))
```

It seems like you need to figure out how to make your real `number_of_payments` look like your sample one through nesting.

Comment: I see, could you show me how to figure that out please?

Comment: I don't know your domain. You'll have to figure out that logic.

Comment: What do you mean domain? I am confused what you mean

Comment: I guess I'm politely saying that I'm not going to do your job for free.

Comment: Okay, how much do you want?